# Can I have two different websites on the same website (www and non www)?

Tags: dns, web, hosting, server

My website (http://www.Jumzler.com) is different from (http://Jumzler.com)

I heard that the "www" in fact is a subdomain like other subdomains. If you checked the two websites above you will find the one with www is working on WordPress. The other one without the "www" is not the same and when I checked this with the host (GoDaddy) I find that I can install two different apps (open source software) on them. But in the other hand, I never saw such a thing on the internet.

Comment: are you asking a question to what you already have discovered? I'm confused to what the question is

Comment: "you already have discovered" do you mean that I can do what I asked for? I thought about it maybe an error or something I've to edit because as I said above I never saw such a thing before.

Comment: What it sounds like you're asking is can you have www.site.com and *.site.com be independent of each other and you've accidentally had this happen to yourself within godaddy? but to answer your question, Yes. They are in fact different but many websites just point them to the same location

Comment: Great, thank you so much, Tony. I would like to choose your answer as best if you just can add it in an answer. Thanks :D

Comment: there are other reasons to keep them together and to preffer www over non-www here http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/

Comment: I read the article and found that I should use the www over non-www for now as I just started for better results. Another big thanks :). I will search for what should I do with the DNS to solve this case.

Comment: Since you're using GoDaddy as a host, they _should_ be able to fix it for you if it's troubling you. That's what their support is for ;) to use the crap out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, A website with www.domain.tld can be pointed to a different directory than domain.tld.

It is common practice to make sure they both point to the same location and one is favored over the other (in the form of a redirect). Mixing up usage of www and non-www is bad practice and will usually give you a lower rank on search engines however so it's best to keep it consistent throughout the entire website.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, tony. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily a bad practice. It depends on your goals. It can be 80 % a bad practice as 80% of websites have similar goals. So if you want to have two websites the one as non-www and the other as a subdomain with-www, provided that you have figured out how not to confuse your visitors and that you do not mind that the link juice will not pass to your subdomain, as it would in the case of subdirectory, then you can go for it.